# Array definitions in TypeScript

Tags: arrays, typescript

What's the difference between the following declarations:

1. `var num1: [number];`
2. `var num2: number[];`
3. `var num3: Array<number>;`

It seems that `num2` and `num3` are interchangeable, but what about `num1`?

Which declaration should I use when?

Comment: Can you make your question title do more than just name a language and a feature? With 8.69 million questions on Stack Overflow, it is helpful when titles really describe the question.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I am here because of google where I searched for almost the exact same string as this title and ended up here. So disagree.

Comment: @Clark: You got lucky. You're also but a single sample. The benefits of a good, unique question title are both well-documented and self-evident.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1 is a tuple type, so in this case `num1` must be a 1-element array containing a number. If you declare it as `var num1: [number, string, string];` then `num1` must be a 3-element array containing a number, a string and another string in that order.

2 and 3 are identical; it doesn't matter which one you use.

Comment: Compare the dry pages of documentation to the first 2 lines of this answer. I came here to see the difference between [] and <> for arrays, and ended up understanding tuple types. Awesome.